# Recording data of neighboring text

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am working on a Mac using Pycharm and the Selenium Library. Below is the link of some websites I am working with.

https://www.bu.edu/phpbin/course-search/section/?t=caspy211

https://www.bu.edu/phpbin/course-search/section/?t=casma124

Basically, this is a link to one of the classes offered at Boston University. You can see how the table shows the different schedules for each of the classes. There are 3 different types of classes. Lectures (LEC), Discussion (DIS) and Labs (LAB).

I am trying to make my code analyze the page by locating the each type of class. In this case, I would like my program to scan through the page, to locate all the occurrences of the word LEC and return the schedule and location.

I have tried to use inspect to look at the XPaths for the occurrences of the word "LEC" and how that pattern could maybe tie up to the Schedule Rubric. But I was not able to find a solution. I feel like there could be a simpler way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can work on the below rough lines. Hope this helps:-

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.bu.edu/phpbin/course-search/section/?t=caspy211'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
df1 = df_list[-2]
df2 = df_list[-3]
dfLec = (df2[df2['Type'].str.contains("lec",case=False,na=False)])
```

Comment: I have never used these two libraries. I kinda understand the first few lines. But correct me if I am wrong. The first lines basically scan through the url and convert it into html to be analyzed. But then what are the values you have assigned to df, df1 and df2? what does dfLec do exactly? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is there a way for me to be able to visualize what the lines of code do ? I have tried to use print statements but nothing shows up on the console. I though that because is is analyzing the webpage I could make a txt file and paste what df_list does to it.. But it does not work.

Comment: read_html reads the HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects. We then slice the list elements to take table we require in this case since i didnt know which table you require so stored it in three different dataframe. You can actually see the variable explorer in Spyder or similar IDE to see the assigned values.
you can visit https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html for more info on it